# I am trying to do a npm start after npm build, I am getting this error

Tags: npm, npm-start

Failed to compile
./src/components/LoginScreen.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@daml.js/MythirdDamlApp' in 'C:\Users\uclick\Desktop\Data\babasD\Misc\SmartContracts\MythirdDamlApp\ui\src\components'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.